# I need to update data for multiple selected users (use in clause)

Tags: java, mysql

```
for (int i = 0; i < useridArr.length; i++) {
    DbUtil.executeUpdate(
              conn, Mysql.insert_announcement, 
              new Object[]{
                   useridArr[i], companyid, msg, announcerid, 0, 1, 
                   new java.util.Date().getTime()
              });
}
```

Now, I want to avoid this for loop, please suggest me what I need to do?

Comment: Please elaborate. Why? What does it do? What do you want it to do?

Comment: i want update multiple data without use for loop

Comment: @BipilRaut: Edit and improve the question. Add more details. What is the expected and actual output?

Comment: In every case you can make a JDBC batch out of it; much faster. First look whether the SQL can be changed is something like USER_ID IN (?)

Comment: may be possible use for in clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now, the loop will execute one insert statement for each user id in the given array `useridArr`. It is not clear from your question why you need to change this.
I will assume you want to improve the performances. The way to do that is to use a batch insert instead of the multiple inserts.

Anyway, you will need to loop through the user ids to initialise the statement values even if it will execute once.

You could add a new helper in `DbUtil` (add exception handling and return as you need)

```
public class DbUtil {
   public static void executeBatchUpdate(Connection con, 
                                         String stmt
                                         List<Object[]> data) {
      PreparedStatement p = con.prepareStatement(stmt);
      for (Object[] rowData : data) {
         for (int i = 0; i < rowData.length; i++) {
            p.setObject(i+1, rowData[i]);
         }
         p.addBatch();
      }
      int[] results = p.executeBatch();
      // check results
      // handle exceptions
      // return something if needed
   }
}
```

And build the `List<Object[]>` in a loop like

```
List<Object[]> data = new ArrayList<>(useridArr.length);
for (int i = 0; i < useridArr.length; i++) {
    data.add(new Object[]{
                   useridArr[i], companyid, msg, announcerid, 0, 1, 
                   new java.util.Date().getTime()
             });
}
```

You can also have a more specialised batch insert method that takes directly the values, prepare the batch and execute it, without building the intermediate list of rows `Object[]`.